# Merging multiples lists with same length when matching conditions

Tags: python-3.x

given input: `theList = [<userID>,<number_of_views>]`

```
theList = [
    [[3, 5], [1, 1], [2, 3]],
    [[1, 2], [3, 5], [3, 0], [2, 3], [4, 2]],
    [[1, 2], [3, 5], [3, 0], [2, 3], [4, 2]],
    [[1, 2], [1, 1], [4, 2]]
]

expected output = [
    [[3, 5], [2, 3], [1, 1]],
    [[3, 5], [2, 3], [1, 2], [4, 2]],
    [[3, 5], [2, 3], [1, 2], [4, 2]],
    [[1, 3], [4, 2]]
]

for sublist in theList:
```

e.x -->

```
theList[3] = [[1,2], [1,1], [4,2]]
```

how to merge items that have same userIDs = 1 in this case and sum all the corresponding views to this (userID=1) (2+1) = 3 views into a new_list --> [1,3]

```
expected theList[3] = [[1,3], [4,2]].
```

How could I make this process for all theList?

Thanks so much for spending time on this question!

Comment: so you want to sum every second value that have the same first value : `[[x, a], [x, b],[y, c], [y, d]] => [[x, a+b], [y, c+d]]` ?

Comment: yes, correctly Artog!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using `collections.defaultdict`.

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

theList = [
    [[3, 5], [1, 1], [2, 3]],
    [[1, 2], [3, 5], [3, 0], [2, 3], [4, 2]],
    [[1, 2], [3, 5], [3, 0], [2, 3], [4, 2]],
    [[1, 2], [1, 1], [4, 2]]
]

result = []
for i in theList:
    r = defaultdict(int)
    for j, k in i:
        r[j] += k
    result.append(list(r.items()))

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[(3, 5), (1, 1), (2, 3)],
 [(1, 2), (3, 5), (2, 3), (4, 2)],
 [(1, 2), (3, 5), (2, 3), (4, 2)],
 [(1, 3), (4, 2)]]
```